# Lottery draw problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, lotteries

In addition to $7$ ordinary numbers (chosen out of 34 in this case), there are drawn 3 bonus numbers. In order to win the second prize, one needs $6$ numbers plus $1$ from the 3 bonus ones. I am wondering what is the probability of winning the second prize in this case?

I suppose there are $7$ ways to pick $6$ numbers from the initial slot, and therefore $27$ ways to pick the last number on the ticket($34-7$). We then have $3$ ways to choose $1$ number out of the bonus ones, and thus a total of $34$ numbers to choose for that one. I am not sure, however, how to calculate the probability of winning the prize here...

So maybe $34\cdot27$ times more likely to win the second prize than the first prize. But then I need to figure out the probability of winning the first prize...

Comment: Can you show your calculations for the first prize

Comment: @trueblueanil; Right, I don't have them...

Comment: For the first prize, there are $\binom{34}7$  combos of $7$ whereas only one of them will win you the prize, hence $Pr = \frac{1}{\binom{34}7}$. Can you now make a try ro compute the *Pr* for  the second prize ?

Comment: @trueblueanil; Thank you for that, would multiplying by $34\cdot27$ yield the correct probability then?

Comment: No, you need any  $6$ out of $7$ right from $34$ *together with* $1$ right from $3$

Comment: @trueblueanil; Which implies...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach the problem combinatorically.

The probability of coming in $2$nd place is

$$\frac{\binom{7}{6} \times \binom{3}{1}}{\binom{34}{7}}. \tag1 $$

The explanation is:

- The denominator, $~\displaystyle \binom{34}{7}~$ represents the total number of ways of filling out the ticket.
- Without loss of generality, assume that the winning  numbers (in some order) are $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}.$ 
  Also assume that the $(3)$ bonus numbers, in some order, are $\{8,9,10\}$.
- In order to determine how many of the $~\displaystyle \binom{34}{7}~$ tickets will specifically come in $2$nd place, you have to determine how many such tickets will have exactly $(6)$ of the numbers from $\{1,2,\cdots,7\}$ and exactly $(1)$ of the numbers from $\{8,9,10\}$.  This explains the numerator in (1) above.

Comment: The danish (national (?, I think they were back then) lottery used to look quite similar to this around 30 years ago (only they drew only 2 bonus numbers). In that you would win 3rd prize if you would get 6 of the 7 winning numbers and none of the bonus numbers. But this calculation would suggest the probability of that is *lower* then for this combination, quite atypical with a lower probability for a lower prize (3rd instead of 2nd), also they would say that more people got 3rd prize then 2nd.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity The probability of getting exactly $6$ of the $7$ numbers drawn, and $1$ number that is in the subset of $~(34 - 7 - 2 = 25)~$ numbers is $$\frac{\binom{7}{6} \times \binom{25}{1}}{\binom{34}{7}}.$$  The above probability (of coming in $3$rd) is therefore greater than the original poster's probability of coming in $2$nd.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, it appears that everything is drawn from the pool of $34$ numbers (although in many lotteries they have two separate pools of numbers)

so there are $7$ for first prize, $3$ "bonus" numbers, $24$ others, and for the second prize,

what you need are $6$ from the first group, $1$ from the second, and $0$ from the third

Thus P(win second prize) $= \binom76\binom31\binom{24}0\large/\binom{34}7$